# laravel GuzzleHttp post with csrf

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to post request to first server using GuzzleHttp on second server
http://imei.sy/imei
Which have csrf_field()
the errors:
500 Internal error` response
so How to post with csrf_filed

I make same server (locally)

when I stopped csrf on first server  post success

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\each;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class Guz extends Controller
{
    //
    //public $url = "http://127.0.0.1:8001/add";
    public $url = "http://imei.sy/imei";

    // Make Get request , re
    public function getGuzzleRequest()
        {
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $request = $client->get($this->url);
            $response = $request->getBody();
        // dd( (string) $response);
        return $this->get_string_between( (string) $response,"token\" content=\"","\">");

        }
public function postGuzzleRequest()
    {

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $body = [
            'imei' => '99999',
            //'price' => 333,
            '_token'=> $this->getGuzzleRequest()

        ];
        $r = $client->request('POST', $this->url, [

            'form_params' => $body
       ]);

        $response = $r->getBody()->getContents();

        dd($response);


    }

    private function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){ // Get
    if($start != ''){ 
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($ini == 0) return '';
        $ini += strlen($start);
    }
    else{
        $ini = 0;
    }

    if ($end == '') { 
        return substr($string, $ini);
    }
    else{
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini; 
        return substr($string, $ini, $len);
    }
}
}


Route::get('/guzg',"Guz@getGuzzleRequest");
Route::get('/guzp',"Guz@postGuzzleRequest");
```

the errors:
419 unknown status` response

Answer (score 3):

You need get **csrf_token** from response and use this token in next auth request

```
$client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://example.com/',
        'cookie' => true,
        'verify' => false,
        'allow_redirects' =>  true
    ]);


    $cookieJar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();

    $response = $client->get('/sign_in', [
        'cookie' => true,
        'cookies' => $cookieJar,
    ]);

    //get token
    preg_match('/<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="(.*)"/Uis',$response->getBody()->getContents(), $login_csrf);;
    

    $response = $client->post( '/sign_in', [
        'form_params' => [
            'login' => 'login',
            'password' => 'password',
            '_token' => $login_csrf['1'],
        ],
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xm…ml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0',

        ],
        'cookies' => $cookieJar,
        'debug' => false,
        'on_stats'=>function (TransferStats $stats){
            echo $stats->getEffectiveUri()."\n";
        },
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the api reference](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html), you pass the headers as params to the request:

```
 $r = $client->request('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/add', [
      'headers'     => ['X-CSRF-Token'=> csrf_token()]
      'form_params' => $params
 ]);
```

Comment: Is the problem that CSRF token is not passed correctly (see request logs) or it is incorrect?

Comment: GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (419)
Client error: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8001/add` resulted in a `419 unknown

Comment: I tried to POST on postman after get token from GET request 
and set on the POST body 
'_token' 'ewetwetewtewtetewt'
 work correctly ,
but failed on my code :(

Comment: CSRF tokens change with every request. You need to extract it from the GET request and pass it with the POST request. Read here how it works: https://medium.com/@charithra/introduction-to-csrf-a329badfca49 (scroll to the end)

Comment: I tried it , I make Get request and return token from it , and I passed token to post request but same error , as you said CSRF change with every request , but on postman every thing work correctly :( :( :(

Comment: if you want try on this site
http://imei.sy/imei
it take only 'imei' as post body and '_token' can gotten from get request

Answer (score 0):

I think that use the csrf token is not the correct way to make the auth to the second server, maybe the second server can use an API with oauth2 or jwt as auth.

Comment: you are right , but I can't change that on second server

Comment: Then you need the token of this second server, making some request previously (I think). Then you can make the post request, sending the token as a param.

Comment: I tried to make get request to pick to token and include it on POST request ,
but not work 
On the post man it's work correctly but on my code not work
 `
            //'_token'=> 'uAqHG82kSjnWMXhhSwTvLr7Et8FutLEXz04IC3Oh'
or
'headers'     => ['X-CSRF-Token'=> 'RN5uEm9IVvgUaBYL7PGFiHLH6gM68UmaEVLZgGnK'],
`

NOT working